# What does the F stand for in this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

On [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/) when you enter this integration $π\int_0^1(e^{x^2-1})^2dx$ the value $\frac{πF(\sqrt 2)}{\sqrt 2}$ is returned. 
 This can be seen [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cpi%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft(e%5E%7Bx%5E2-1%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)dx).

My question is what does the $F$ stand for?

Comment: Note that the integrand you entered in symbolab. Maybe you meant [this one](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cpi%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft(e%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D-1%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)dx)? I yhink the $F$ denotes an error function.

Comment: @mickep I do apologise, I put the `}` in the wrong place on the equation. I have updated the question

Comment: Product support, even for mathematical software, is off-topic here.

Comment: @hardmath I was merely asking what the $F$ stands for in mathematical terms. I was not asking for product support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case $F$ stands for the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function).

Comment: So in layman terms what would $F(\sqrt 2)$ be equivalent to?

Comment: @Dan $$e^{-2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}e^{x^2}\,dx.$$